# Sprint boot does not bootstrap index.html

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a angular-spring boot project that is structured like the below image:
[image]

As you see index.html is under resources/static/app and to include this location as resource location I did this :

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcAutoConfiguration.WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter {


    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/app/");
    }
}
```

Now when I run my app on default port 8080, I get a NOT FOUND error.

Anyone has a clue what I am missing here?

Comment: What URL are you using to access the static content?

Comment: I use _http://localhost:8080/#/_ , it works when I move index.html to _static_ directory. But it does not work when it is in _static/app_ directory.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson forgot to mention you.

Comment: That's not surprising. When `index.html` is in `src/main/resources/static/app` its URL is `localhost:8080/app/index.html`

Comment: @AndyWilkinson thank you! so how can I bootstrap my app when hitting _localhost:8080_ ? should I forward all calls to the app/index.html and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the directory you are adding, `app`, is already a sub-directory of the default static resources directory: `src/main/resources/static/app` then you don't need additional configuration to serve content within the `app` directory.

localhost:8080/app/index.html will work out of the box without the additional config used above.

Comment: I removed the configuration but still does not work. When I move index.xml into static it works. According to  [spring-boot-resource-locations](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot) only _src/main/resources/static/_ is a built-in resource location in spring boot, but not _src/main/resources/static/app_

Comment: A resource location includes all of its sub-directories with each sub-directory being part of the path in the resource's URL

Comment: @sansari There must be something else going on in your project.  Please share a full example on GitHub.  Thanks.